# resize.instanceId events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jQuery plugin code, I see the following:

```
$window.on('resize.' + instance.guid, function () {
    instance.registerTimeout('resizeTimeout', function () {
        // stuff
    }, 60);
  });
```

What does such `resize.instanceId` event mean and where does it come from? It does not seem to be anywhere in this library (nor in jQuery itself).

When debugging I see that it is actually triggered for a regular `resize` event.

Comment: [**event.namespace**](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

Answer (score 0):

it is a `namespaced` event. In this case the event is `resize` and the namespace is the value of `instanceId`.

If you have many event handlers attached for the same event a namespace could be useful to detect later which handler you want exactly unbind with `.off('resize.instanceId')`

See http://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/